# Concat 2 columns in a full table view

Tags: mysql

here is an example of what my problem is

```
CustomerID  FirstName   LastName FullName
1           Ken         Weger    Ken Weger
```

this is my output what i need to do is to replace the FirstName and LastName columns with FullName using Concat in a select statement. The code I am getting to create this result looks like this

```
Select *,
Concat (firstname, ' ', lastname) as fullname from customer;
```

Please let me know what i am doing wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Please edit your question (formating it add one line and 4 spaces before the code) so we can understand what you have

Comment: `SELECT *` selects **ALL** columns.  If you do not want all the columns, then you *cannot* use `SELECT *`.  Try: `SELECT CustomerID, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS fullname`.

Comment: ok well someone edited the question i have a total of 11 columns in the original table i need the columns of firstname and last name to be concatenated into a single column while still displaying all the other columns basically what i need to knoiw is do i have to type out each columns name in the select statement to get it to show this with the concat statement in place of firstname and lastname?

Comment: @KenWeger: Yes, you will have to type out all of the columns (minus the ones you don't want).

Comment: Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CustomerID, CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) AS FullName FROM Table
```

select * selects all columns from table.